# Unmarshall the XML string to Java object using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I want to convert the below XML string to Java object using JAXB.

I'm able to convert object but `documents` is coming as `null` after unmarshall. 
 `Result [hits=1, tookInMillis=10, totalHits=1, documents=null]`
 How to correct `documents` object to get values?

**XML String:**

```
<result hits="1" tookInMillis="9" totalHits="1" xmlns="http://www.example.com/search/result/1.0">
   <documents>
      <document id="1" company="TEST" type="CN" generationDate="2018-05-24T06:05:37.000Z">
         <field type="xs:string" name="test1">test1</field>
         <field type="xs:string" name="test2">test2</field>
         <field type="xs:string" name="test3">test3</field>
         <field type="xs:string" name="test4">test4</field>
         <field type="xs:string" name="test5">test5</field>
         <field type="xs:string" name="test6">test6</field>
         <field type="xs:string" name="test7">test7</field>
         <field type="xs:string" name="test8">test8</field>
         <field type="xs:date" name="date">2018-05-23</field>
      </document>
   </documents>
</result>
```

Comment: The XML is not enough to answer that question. Please also post your POJO class and thecode where you unmarshall the XML to a POJO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with the XML namespaces.

In XML a namespace given in an XML element (like in `<result>`)
inherits to its child elements (`<documents>`, `<document>` and `<field>`).

In Java it does not. Therefore you need to give the namespace explicitly
in the `@XmlElement` and `@XmlElementWrapper` annotations of the child properties.

The following Java classes work fine when unmarshalling your XML example.
Especially, the collections `Result.documents` and `Document.fields`
don't come as `null`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "result", namespace = "http://www.example.com/search/result/1.0")
public class Result {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int hits;

    @XmlAttribute
    private int tookInMillis;

    @XmlAttribute
    private int totalHits;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "documents", namespace = "http://www.example.com/search/result/1.0")
    @XmlElement(name = "document", namespace = "http://www.example.com/search/result/1.0")
    private List<Document> documents;

    // ... public getters and setters (omitted for brevity)
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Document {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String company;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute
    private Date generationDate;

    @XmlElement(name = "field", namespace = "http://www.example.com/search/result/1.0")
    private List<Field> fields;

    // ... public getters and setters (omitted for brevity)
}
```

Comment: It is working now, i'm able to get the document object values. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have not added namespace for  List<Document> documents and List<Field> fields,  as you mentioned after adding namespace its working fine.